# oauth 2.0 integration with peoplesoft

Tags: oauth-2.0, peoplesoft

Our existing customer base is in peoplesoft and we are developing lot of mobile applications. Hence, we would like to use oauth 2.0 for authentication and authorization, but i cannot find any way to integrate the two.

Answer (score 1):

Does PS implement OAuth? If they don't then you'll be out of luck. A quick search indicates they support SAML for SSO (on their web sites). You will probably have to describe a little bit more what you are doing, and why you think OAuth is the way to go.

> Note that being mobile doesn't necessarily mean you **have to** implement OAuth.

Comment: We have rest based backend services. The mobile app needs to invoke them. I mentioned oauth as i have not seen SAML being used with rest based services.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer, but as of PeopleTools 8.58, PeopleSoft applications support OAuth2 for REST services. The caveat is that only Oracle IDCS is able to be used as an authorization server. There may be a plan in the future to support other authorization servers.

Cf. https://blogs.oracle.com/peopletools/what-peoplesoft-is-doing-with-oauth2-in-858 and https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/PeopleSoft%20Enterprise/2621182_1.html for more information.